# Manually setting the value of form Array element inside reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

This is driving me nuts and I'm already overwhelmed by this, this is my 2nd full day to make this work but still in vain

My form values are not being displayed in html I'm working on dynamic table, where I don't know the number of rows in advance. The problem is that the calculated total doesn't show up in html even though its value is saved in component object.

here is my html code

```
<table style="overflow-x: auto;display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">
    <thead>
        <tr class='tableHeader'>
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                <td fxFlex="22" class="pr-4">Name</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Price</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Loan Term</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Quantity</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Deposit</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Total</td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr formArrayName="products" *ngFor="let product of loanProductForm.get('products').controls; let i = index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                <td fxFlex="22">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Product </mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="productId" [id]="'productId' + i" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productList" [value]="product.productId">
                                {{product.name}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>

                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Price </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' (keyup)="onPriceChange($event)" matInput formControlName="price"
                            [id]="'price' + i" name="" placeholder="Price" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Loan Term </mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="loanTermId" [id]="'loanTermId' + i" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let loanTerm of loanTermList" [value]="loanTerm.loanTermId">
                                {{loanTerm.numberOfMonths}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Quantity </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="quantity" [id]="'quantity' + i" matInput name="" id=""
                            placeholder="Quantity" required>

                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Deposit </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="deposit" [id]="'deposit' + i" matInput name="" id=""
                            placeholder="Deposit" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Total </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="total" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="total" id=""
                            placeholder="Total" style="color:black; font-weight:bold" required>
                        <!-- <input disabled type='number' [(ngModel)]="totalValue" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="total" id="" placeholder="Total" style="color:black; font-weight:bold" required> -->
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>

            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td fxFlex="10">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                    <button type="button" mat-stroked-button class='addBtn btn-style-2' fxFlex='100'
                        (click)='addProductButtonClick()'>Add
                        <mat-icon matSuffix>add_box</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my component code

```
this.loanProductForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      products: this._formBuilder.array([
        this.addProductFormGroup()
      ])
    });



 addProductButtonClick(): void {

    (<FormArray>this.loanProductForm.get('products')).push(this.addProductFormGroup());
    console.log('Loan Products: ', this.loanProductForm.value)

  }


addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      productId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: [0, Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: [0, Validators.required],
      deposit: [0, Validators.required],
      total: [0, Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

even though it saves fine in my `object` but it doesn't showsup in html. 
The formula to calculate total value is (price*quantity) - deposit =total

here is what I already tried, besides this I tried to juggle around the `form` object to see if the values are being changed or not in forms, they accept the the change in `object` but doesn't show in html

```
this.loanProductForm.valueChanges.subscribe((values) => {
  values.products.forEach(product => {
    product.total = (product.quantity * product.price) - product.deposit
  })

  console.log('Updated values of form are: ', values.products)
})
```

I just want to update the `total` value in each row
Thanks in advance. I'm utterly exhausted by trying to make this work.
Once again thanks in advance to helping hands

[image: Picture for better understanding]

Comment: Are you trying to set up total amount on the first load or the problem is occurring when you are trying to add element through the add button?

Comment: Not the first load, I want to total to be calculated when I enter the input of `price`, ` quantity` and ` deposit`. and same for each row

Comment: you can use in .html directly:`{{(+products.get('quantity ').value)*(+products.get('price').value)-(+products.get('deposi').value) }}`. See that the "+" before products.get('...').value is for converto to number the value

Answer (score 1):

Well what you need is. When you create a form group you need to subscribe to changes and update the total value.

```
 addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    const group = this._formBuilder.group({
      productId: ["", Validators.required],
      price: [0, Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ["", Validators.required],
      quantity: [0, Validators.required],
      deposit: [0, Validators.required],
      total: [0, Validators.required]
    });
    const quantity = group.get("quantity");
    const price = group.get("price");
    const deposit = group.get("deposit");
    const onChange = r => {
      if (r.price && r.quantity) {
        const total = r.price * r.quantity - r.deposit;
        group.patchValue(
          { total: total },
          { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false } // emitEvent is crucial else it will cause and endless loop
        );
      }
    }; 
    group.valueChanges.subscribe(r => onChange(r));
    return group;
  }
```

Stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-w5sewp).